# what kind of data is in storage trie?

Tags: go-ethereum, storage-trie

Hello I have a question about storage trie in Ethereum.

I read many articles but there is no mention about what data is in storage trie.

So, Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The storage trie is where the smart contract data is stored, note that this is not part of the block (only the root of the storage root is stored in the block-header) because this data can be retrieved from the transactions.

The article posted below by @Gabriel actually has an explanation of ethereum world state, including the storage trie. See this also [How data is stored in ethereum](https://hackernoon.com/getting-deep-into-ethereum-how-data-is-stored-in-ethereum-e3f669d96033)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Now I know the smart contract data is stored in storage trie.
But I want to know more specifically like 'how they store in trie' or 'Solidity code is stored?'. 
Can you let me know if there are articles about it?

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit it is hard to find good explanations about what is stored in the Merkel Trie. [This article](https://medium.com/cybermiles/diving-into-ethereums-world-state-c893102030ed) was, to me, very useful I hope it help you as well

"A storage trie is where all of the contract data lives. Each Ethereum account has its own storage trie. A 256-bit hash of the storage trie’s root node is stored as the storageRoot value in the global state trie (which we just discussed).
"
(extracted from article above)

Comment: First thank you for your helping, but I already checked the article and also no what I wanted . thanks again :)

Comment: Can you post the part of the article you think is helping as a quote here ? Links only answers are not accepted.